# Combining jQuery UI Autocomplete Sources

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have achieved functionality that I like with the following source tag:

```
source: function (request, response) {
                 // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                 response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
             },
```

I have achieved new functionality by using the following source tag:

```
source: function (request, response) {
                // Using a custom source callback to match only the beginning of terms
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response($.grep(availableTags, function (item) {
                    return matcher.test(item);
                }));
            }
```

How can I combine these two source tags so that I can have the functionality of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this (just pass the results of `extractLast` into the regular expression instead of the entire term):

```
source: function (request, response) {
    var term = extractLast(request.term),
        matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

    response($.grep(availableTags, function (item) {
        return matcher.test(item);
    }));
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nK/6/

What both are doing:

- The first one is filtering autocomplete terms based on the last item the user typed (delineated by a `,`)
- The second is creating a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) based on the term the user typed. The `^` means "starting with", followed by a utility function that removes any special characters from the term, and finally the `i` parameter which is making the regular expression case-insensitive.
- Combining them is just a matter of extracting the last term (with `extractLast`, and then creating a regular expression based on that term.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much.  That is awesome.  It was really hard for me to understand (still is, actually; but at least I can try to study it).

Comment: @user1477388: Glad I could help! I went into a little more detail on what's going on, hope that clarifies things.

Comment: That was a good explanation.  Will help me moving forward.  Thanks, again, Andrew.